# .Net 6 DLL file is not being updated with AssemblyVersion reference found in .csproj file

Tags: c#, versioning

I have a Blazor app that the generated DLL does not get updated with the referenced `<AssemblyVersion>2022.01.14.1</AssemblyVersion>` found in the .csproj file.

Nor does the `<FileVersion>` and `<Version>`

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit)
Version 17.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the 'Generate assembly info' option selected in the project properties:

[image]

(which is the GenerateAssemblyInfo property in the .csproj file)

```
 <GenerateAssemblyInfo>True</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
```

Then the Version property in the first PropertyGroup of the .csproj file will make it through to the file version property in Explorer:

```
<Version>1.0.1<Version>
```

[image]

If you have a PropertyGroup with the typical AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion properties as seen in AssemblyInfo.cs then those will be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

How do you check the version, from the code or from the file properties?

I tried the scenario you described on a Blazor application, and after building the project in the properties of the .dll file I can see all versions I set in the .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings> 
    <AssemblyVersion>2022.01.14.1</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>2022.01.14.1</FileVersion>
    <Version>3.3.3.3-xyz</Version>
```

And the result can be seen in the image below:

[image]

Is it possible that some other external process changes the version in the files after you build?

Comment: @Alboni - if I check the dll after the build of the project the version has not been changed.

Comment: I use file explorer by going to the file selecting it then alt + enter to bring up the properties.

Comment: You can check the file properties from powershell as well: `[Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo('C:\Temp\MyApp\MyApp.dll')`